# DocuSign: Embedded signing, can you create the envelope in the UI?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk

We are going to send out an email to thousands of clients via some email provider. In that email there will be a link `www.oursite.com?code=123`. The user will click a button on our site which will either direct the user to docusign or open a modal containing that specific users contract.

Each user will have a different renewal price in the contract so it's important we authenticate the user using our code "123".

1. When the user clicks the sign button on our website do we then have to create the envelope containing various details which includes the renewal price?
2. Or can we have envelope in draft, created in the UI, which we will call and display to the user?

We would prefer option 2 as the marketing people create the envelopes in the UI. It is also worth noting, we have several marketing people who all have their own inboxes under our one company account.

If it is the former then we will need a way to figure out which details to include for which using when creating an envelope in the API. Any suggestions on how to best handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have to modify it after it was created to include a **clientUserId**

Without this value you cannot use embedded signing.

This can be done if the envelope is in "draft" (or created) state, but if it was already sent out - it cannot.